# Is Heroku a replacement for a VPS?

Tags: heroku

We're currently evaluating Heroku to replace the initial workflow of renting a VPS for a small Web App (since we're working on NodeJS, cPanel hosting plans aren't enough, ergo, VPS).

The confusion lies in Heroku's actual usage as even though it's clear it's used as a platform as a service, there is no Disk (HDD/SSD) limit described.

Web App requirement includes file upload capabilities (profile picture, etc) so I'm not sure Heroku is what we need. Can I get a clear explanation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a Heroku expert, but...
You could always use one of the various add-ins that offer database support for storing your images until that no longer works

As the usage of your site scales out, you'd probably want to place static content into a CDN.

I wouldn't consider placing files into Heroku that weren't related to running code and honestly I don't even know if you *can*.

(I originally just wanted to comment, but need a higher rep :/)